# Grafana : /metrics endpoint requires authentication

Tags: authentication, kubernetes-helm, grafana, endpoint

https://localhost:8443/grafana/metrics : We have implemented Grafana as a helm using helm- chart and above url endpoint is exposed without authentication. We need this to be accessed using authentication only.

On github, found the same for Grafana. (Reference: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/14077 ) But same is not available on Grafana using helm-chart . Can we achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values.yaml for the helm chart just controls how you want to deploy grafana.

In the values file you can set `grafana.ini` for config (https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L668)

So in that you can set `metrics.basic_auth_username`:

values.yaml:

```
grafana.ini:
  metrics:
    basic_auth_username: MyUser
    basic_auth_password: MyPassword
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, working fine for us. Just could you please tell how /metrics endpoint can be accessed from browser with credentials after applying this